# php command line not executing the php file

Tags: command-line, debian, php-7.3

I am using Php 7.3 on Debian 10. It functions well with various clients installed (Drupal, etc.).

However, with a simple file in a directory such as `/var/www/some_directory/index.php`, the file fails to execute and displays the PHP code (`some_directory` is not `*/public_html`).

When I simply use the command line:

```
php -f /var/www/some_directory/index.php
```

I get the same error, which leads me to think that it is not related to the Apache2 configuration.

The content of the index.php file is fairly straightforward:

```
<html>
  <body>
    You have been redirected.
    <php?
      echo "This is a test";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

What confuses me even more is that if I type:

```
php <<< '<?php echo "This is a test";?>'
```

I get the expected behaviour.

What on earth is happening?  Can someone help?

The .htaccess is just below this line. Its a lame copy of the Drupal .htaccess (hoping this would fix the bug).

Here is the file. Its a lame copy (with adaptations) of the .htaccess file contained in drupal directory (I was hoping this would be a quick fix).

```
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|install|make|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|twig|t\
pl(\.php)?|xtmpl|yml)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\.(?!well-known).*|En\
tries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock)|web\.config)$|^#.*#$\
|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)$">
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>


Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz



<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value assert.active                   0
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
  php_value always_populate_raw_post_data   -1
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Here is the apache.conf file:

```
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess                
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf                           
<FilesMatch \.php$>
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: that is probably because drupal is installed in a directory that apache interprets php, or/and there is a .htaccess that enables php for this directory.

Comment: please post the apache configuration and the .htaccess of this directory

Comment: I just added the .htaccess file.

Comment: Its a debian setup. Its at  /usr/bin/php .

Comment: please take a look at the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a typo, try it like this

```
<html>
  <body>
    You have been redirected.
    <?php
      echo "This is a test";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

or you can use it with the shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<html>
  <body>
    You have been redirected.
    <?php
      echo "This is a test";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. So much for digging in the server configuration. Thanks! :)

Comment: sometimes things are wired ;-)